# What is the easiest way to get the difference in months between two dates in C#?

Tags: c#, date

What is the easiest way to get the difference in months between two dates in C#?

ie: (date1 - date2).TotalMonths .. kind of thing. thanks!

Comment: You should make clear what you mean by 'the difference in months'.  For example, would you want 31 Jan 2010 to 1 Feb 2010 to have a difference of 1 month?

Comment: Yes i would want it to be a difference of 1 month in that case.

My requirements dictate that date1 and date2 will always be the first of a given month. thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer with a comment, and will actually update my answer text given this new info.

Comment: Here is the simple and short code in case, you still couldn't get the answer, see this
[POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820603/how-a-month-is-defined-in-the-rest-of-the-world) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8820603/how-a-month-is-defined-in-the-rest-of-the-world

Answer (score 5):

Given the updates you have made to your original question: How about writing up a function that takes two dates and does the following,

```
DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2008, 12, 1);
DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2009, 1, 1);

var month_diff = (d2.Year - d1.Year)*12 + (d2.Month - d1.Month);
Console.WriteLine(month_diff);
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you already know that your dates will be the first of the month:

```
int totalMonths = (date2.Year - date1.Year)*12 + date2.Month - date1.Month;
```

Answer (score 2):

The best I can suggest is to get the total number of days, and then roughly compute the number of months by dividing accordingly.  Something like:

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime( 2010, 10, 23);
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime( 2010, 7, 23);
TimeSpan ts = dt1 - dt2;
int days_per_month = 30;
Console.Write( ts.TotalDays / days_per_month);
```

If you really are okay with something like 2010 Feb 1 - 2010 Jan 31 returning 1 month as its answer, then given the above code, you would be able to get at this easily by using

```
Console.Write( dt1.Month - dt2.Month);
```

This doesn't take into consideration the year, so I defer to the other answer here that does this.  :)

Comment: yeah thanks.. i have that now.. but not really accurate enough. I know with a larger method i can accurately calculate it.. just wondering if there is an easier way i am missing.

Comment: can you define "accuracy" when applied to a non-specific unit time like the month?  :)

Comment: I just saw your comment to your original post.  In this case, where Feb 1 - Jan 31 is one month, you just have to subtract the Month properties, i.e. dt1.Month - dt2.Month.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know how to calculate date span in .net here is good example:

> ```
> DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
> DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(75);
>
> TimeSpan span = endTime.Subtract ( startTime );
> Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (seconds): " + span.Seconds );
> Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (minutes): " + span.Minutes );
> Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (hours): " + span.Hours );
> Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (days): " + span.Days );
> ```

Source: [here](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/458-How-find-difference-between-two-Dates-C-or.aspx).

DateTime don't expose the difference in month since every month have a different number of days. The simplest way to get the month is `totaldays / 30`.

Comment: Have to agree... the question wasn't crystal clear, but this misses the mark by a wide margin, it's just a transparent copy-and-paste job from the very first Google hit for the exact text of the question. -1.

Answer (score 0):

[TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332448%28VS.71%29.aspx) Class :)

```
 TimeSpan span = endTime.Subtract ( startTime );
 Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (months): " + span.Days / 30 );
```

Comment: What about it? is that the easiest way?

Comment: It's inaccurate as months have varying number of days.

Comment: @ Will Agreed :) Since he is using a "Large" unit, I just assumed he needs a rough value ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int GetMonthDifference(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
{
    if (date1 > date2)
    {
        DateTime swap = date1;
        date1 = date2;
        date2 = swap;
    } 
    return ((date2.Year * 12) + date2.Month) - ((date1.Year * 12) + date1.Month);
}
```